# how to call data in search box at 3rd character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-mobile

Here am calling input id in ul data input. Whenever there are three characters in input tag, then only ul data input should call. Below is "input id"

```
<input data-type="search" placeholder="Search here..." name="sales_return_product" id="sales_return_product" data-mini="true">

<ul id="sal_product" data-role="listview" data-insert="true" data-filter="true"  data-filter-reveal="true" data-input="#sales_return_product" data-theme="a"></ul>
```

How to increase the search performance from json data in list view

Comment: Your question make very little sense, so it's hard to know what you're trying to do, let alone provide a solution

Comment: am filtering the data in list view through search view on third character..
like whenever i write the 3 character in search view then i shoud start filtering the data in list view